# Finding interval of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I need help finishing this problem.
series is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n^2}e^{-nx}$

I calculated the radius of convergence $\frac{1}{lim_{n\to\infty} ((1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n^2})^{\frac{1}{n}}} = \frac{1}{e}$

I have trouble figuring out the interval of convergence, because there is $e^{-nx}$ instead of (x-x0)^n. I know that $e^{-nx}=(e^{-x})^{n}$

Can someone explain to me how should I proceed?

Comment: @MarkViola Formating error sorry, I fixed it

Comment: Use the root test.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks, I got the correct answer x>-1 , but is there a way to solve it using intervals meaning: interval of convergence: (xo-r, xo+r)?

Comment: A side note: This is not a power series in $x$, so it is not appropriate to use the term "radius of convergence". The term "interval of convergence" may possibly used, but whether the set of all values of $x$ where the series converges forms an interval or not is no longer guaranteed and needs to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n^2}e^{-nx}$. By root test, if $lim (a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is smaller than 1 then the series converges. But $(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n(e^x)}\rightarrow \frac{1}{e.e^x}=\frac{1}{e^{x+1}}$. So to have convergence we must have $\frac{1}{e^{x+1}} < 1 \Rightarrow 1 < e^{x+1} \Rightarrow 0<x+1 \Rightarrow -1<x.$

Answer (score 1):

You have a functions series $\sum_{n}f_{n}(x)$ the power series $\sum_{n}a_{n}x^{n}$ is a particular case of functions series.

We have that
$$|e^{-nx}|\leqslant e^{-n\alpha},\quad \forall x\geqslant \alpha>0$$
Then,
$$\left|\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^{2}}e^{-nx}\right|\leqslant \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^{2}}e^{-n\alpha},\quad \forall x\geqslant \alpha$$
Using $n-$th root test, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^{2}}e^{-n\alpha}<+\infty.$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^{2}}e^{-nx}$$ converges uniformly by Weierstrass M-Test for all $x\in [\alpha,+\infty[$.

What can you said about the convergence for the series? Just use $n-$th root test.